# Remove specific entire word from a string

Tags: c#

I have this text file that contains these 3 lines:

```
Bob
MikeBob
Mike
```

How could I remove 'Mike' without removing 'Mike' from 'MikeBob'?

I have tried this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("C:/data.txt");
text = text.Replace("Mike", "");
```

But it removed all occurrences of Mike.
What should I do?

Comment: Unless there's a `\r` in there too.

Comment: Do you want an empty line where Mike was or remove the entire line?

Comment: Read all lines and exclude the word then rebuild text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("C:/data.txt"), "\bMike\b","");
```

Pretty easy through regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
// input string 
String str = "Hello.???@@.##$ here,#$% my%$^$%^&is***()&% this"; 

// similar to Matcher.replaceAll 
str = Regex.Replace(str,@"[^\w\d\s]","");
```